# What is the best way to replicate a region?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I make minigames, let's use the example skywars for right now.

I normally recreate the maps (replace broken blocks, destroy placed blocks) with about 20 `/clone` commands.

I have also been looking at if structure blocks would be faster, since upon map generation you have to wait through 10-20 seconds of 1 FPS until the map is done and you would be teleported.

Are structure blocks or `clone` better, or is there another method?

Comment: Can you create command blocks in your version ?

Comment: @Radon8472 yes but commands are different in Bedrock and Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I have found that cloning a few structure blocks, activating them, then clearing them is so much faster than the `/clone` command entirely. The time taken goes from like 30 seconds to 2 seconds and minimal lag.

Answer (score -1):

When the "region" you like to replicate can be an entiry 1024x1024 Blocks Area, you could simple backup the matching `*.mca` from your `region` folder.

Keep in mind region files are separated for each dimension:

- `region` = overworld
- `DIM1` = nether
- `DIM-1` = Void

Another way could be to create a `.mcfunction` file with all your cloning commands, than you must only run run ONE command to activate your function with `/function your_function`.

Read how to use function files at https://minecraft.wiki/w/Function_(Java_Edition)

Comment: This isn't Java Edition